# gets() in function gets skipped after second use

Tags: c++, cin, getline, gets

I'm trying to make a text input function, like this `InputText` function below:

```
char* InputText(char Dummy[256])
{
    gets(Dummy);
    return Dummy;
}
```

But when the function is called again, `gets(Dummy)` get skipped. I have researched this problem through StackOverflow (by using `cin.ignore()` or `cin.clear()`) and I can't seem to find the right answer and explanation.

Here's my program for the function:

```
#define pr_ cout<<
#define in_ cin>>

#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

char* InputText(char Dummy[256]);

main()
{
    char Quest;
    do
    {
        char InputChar[256];
        int InputLength;

        pr_ "\n Input text (Note: press Enter twice to finish input.)\n >";
        InputText(InputChar);

        InputLength=strlen(InputChar);

        pr_ "\n You inputted : "<<InputChar;
        pr_ "\n String length: "<<InputLength;
        do
        {
            pr_ "\n\n Restart program?\n >";
            in_ Quest;
            if(Quest!='y' && Quest!='Y' && Quest!='n' && Quest!='N')
            pr_ " System error: not an answer.";
        }
        while(Quest!='y' && Quest!='Y' && Quest!='n' && Quest!='N');
    }
    while(Quest=='y' || Quest=='Y');
}

char* InputText(char Dummy[256])
{
    gets(Dummy);
    return Dummy;
}
```

Here's the example of the program output, with the problem I mentioned:

```
Input text (Note: press Enter twice to finish input.)
>I am Groot!

You inputted : I am Groot!
String length: 11

Restart program?
>y

Input text (Note: press Enter twice to finish input.)
>
You inputted :
String length: 0

Restart program?
>
```

So my question: How do I make the `gets()` part not getting skipped? *Sorry if I re-asked this question.*

**UPDATE 1**: From **R Sahu**'s answer, I am now using `fgets()`. But it's still skipped.

Comment: The real question is why are you using `gets`? It doesn't even exist in the most recent version of the standard.

Comment: Fun macros. No, not really.

Comment: @chris Now I'm using `fgets()`, but it's still getting skipped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using

```
    do
    {
        pr_ "\n\n Restart program?\n >";
        in_ Quest;
        cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        if(Quest!='y' && Quest!='Y' && Quest!='n' && Quest!='N')
        pr_ " System error: not an answer.";
    }
```

works for me.

Words of caution:

Please don't use `gets`. It is a source of security problems. Use `fgets` instead. See [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used).

Comment: No, it's not that part. I'm asking about the `InputText` function, the "Restart program?" part doesn't have any problems.

Comment: Without the `cin.ingore` line, a `'\n'` left on the stream. The next call to `gets()` returns an empty line.